# filter date does not work in twig it show filter does not exist

Tags: symfony, twig

Am i missing something? (symfony 2.5 and php 5.5.9)

the line that create the error
    `{{post.createdAt|date("F d, Y")}}`

[image: the error]

Comment: Do the other built-in filters/function work? Be sure your loading them corerctly

Comment: how can i check if they are loading correctly?
ps: i tried the capitalize filter it work

Comment: try some other default filters like `default('value')` or `striptags`

Comment: the stiptags also work

Comment: i tried something silly but it worked {{ post.getCreatedAt|createdAt('F d, Y') }}
but i got this new error The filter "date" does not exist. Did you mean "date_modify" in @WebProfiler/Profiler/layout.html.twig at line 25

Comment: The filter `date` should be defined in the file `vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Core.php`. Look if its present (it should be around line line 192 above `date_modify`)

Comment: yes the filter date does not exist but there is a filter named createdAt.
how can i force an update of a vender? (as far as i know no body touched the file)

Comment: The `date` fitler is availabe as of Twig 1.1 so it should be in there definly. Just try to do a `composer update` if you installed through composer

Comment: well this is weird at least i know where the problem is even with composer update it stay the same but i will figure out a solution. Thank you

Comment: Remove the `vendor/twig` directory and run `composer install`.

Comment: yeah i did that and i also i needed delete the cache of composer so therefore he download a new version again